# How to pass table name and column name dynamic in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I was trying to pass table name and column name dynamic, this is as part of SSIS process I am trying this stored procedure below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [lnd].[Get_ANCNotullColumn]
    (@PassedTableName AS NVarchar(255),
     @PassedColumnName AS NVARCHAR(100)) 
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

    SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ';'

    DECLARE @final AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @final = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @PassedColumnName + ' IS NULL  OR ' + @PassedColumnName + '='''

    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

On executing this, I am NOT getting count as result, instead I am getting execution success.

```
EXEC [lnd].[Get_ANCNotullColumn] 'lnd.ANC_LND_ItemOverride', 'comments'
```

I need to get the count as output.

Also my simple direct query is like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM lnd.ANC_LND_ItemOverride  
WHERE Comments IS NULL OR Comments = '' -- 3 is the output
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: @LajosArpad YES

Comment: I have not worked with SQL Server for a very long time, so instead of writing an answer let's start to chat about the problem. You could create a stored function instead of a procedure, declare a count variable, select count(*) into count and return the result. Or, you can keep this as a stored procedure and have an out parameter and select into that out parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to modify you value passing and your concatenation values.

from this statement you need to remove the semi colon as it will throw error

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ';'
```

While passing blank values you need additional quotes

```
SELECT @final = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @PassedColumnName + ' IS NULL  OR ' + @PassedColumnName + '= '''''
```

While execution I believe you wanted to execute final instead of SQL

I think below  should give your output:

```
CREATE PROC [lnd].[Get_ANCNotullColumn]( @PassedTableName as NVarchar(255),@PassedColumnName AS 
     NVARCHAR(100)) 
 AS
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @ActualTableName AS NVarchar(255)

SELECT @ActualTableName = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @ActualTableName + ' '

DECLARE @final AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @final = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @PassedColumnName + ' IS NULL  OR ' + @PassedColumnName + '='''''

EXEC(@final)
END
```